# how does str/ldr knows the register size?

Tags: assembly, arm64, instructions, word-size

aarch64 use `str/ldr` to store/load register into memory:

```
str q0, [dst]
str x0, x1, [dst]
```

In the example above, q0/q1 is 128bit, as well as x1/x0 is 64bit, but how does str/ldp knows the the size of current register? is it related with [word size](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Word_(computer_architecture))?

Comment: The two instructions have different encodings (look them up in the Architecture Reference Manual), and the encoding determines the size of the store.  The assembler looks at which register you have specified in order to decide which instruction to encode.  Just because they have the same mnemonic doesn't mean they get the same encoding.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In asm source, the register name implies the size.
In machine code, the opcode implies the size.

Exactly like `str x0, [dst]` vs. `str w0, [dst]` vs. `strb w0, [dst]`: all 3 assemble to different opcodes which imply different store sizes.

**The fact that some of those opcodes share the `str` mnemonic while others have their own mnemonics is purely a matter of designing the asm source language, and irrelevant to how the CPU decodes and executes it.**

(The choice is motivated by the lack of other instructions that treat a general-purpose register as 8 or 16 bits, like there are on x86.  If you had a whole set of `addb` and `shlb` instructions, the designers of the assembly language might instead make up a byte register names like `x0b` or `b0` or something and use those with mnemonics like `add` and `str`.  Again, that would be somewhat like what x86 does for its "partial register" instructions.  However, m68k has byte/word/long sizes for most instructions, and gets by just fine with `add.b d1, d0` instead of needing to make up names for partial registers.  Like ARM but unlike x86, m68k has no way to access the 2nd byte of a register like x86's AH, so that's probably the real factor that motivates [x86's partial-register naming](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/5121/why-are-first-four-x86-gprs-named-in-such-unintuitive-order).)

Answer (score 0):

- the size of the load/store is determined by the source/destination register name
- Instruction can be suffixed to force a smaller load/store size